# Android scale drawable without quality leak

Tags: android

I have an image `1280x800` and put it to ImageView with

```
animationView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

ImageView on the screen have dimensions `256x160`

When i apply animation to this view, actually

```
    final AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.
            play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animationView, View.SCALE_X, 1f, xScale)).
            with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animationView, View.SCALE_Y, 1f, yScale)).
            with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animationView, View.TRANSLATION_X, currentLocation.x, screenSize.x / 2 - imageWidth / 2)).
            with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(animationView, View.TRANSLATION_Y, currentLocation.y - actionBarHeight, screenSize.y / 2 - imageHeight / 2)).
            with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(actionBarView, View.TRANSLATION_Y, 0, -actionBarHeight));
    set.setDuration(500);
    set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    set.start();
```

xScale and yScale equals ~ 7 of both values. When i scale up this view in 7 times i have a big trouble with quality of drawable inside this view. How can i fix that?

Comment: well you scale up an image greater than its original dimensions, why would you expect it to look just as good as its original?

Comment: @tyczj i have a little imageview at 256x160px on the screen. when i scale up it to original image quality is bad.

Comment: the imageview is an image of just that 256x160 so you are scaling up and image of that size

Comment: @tyczj if i just scale image it will be the next result : image will be scaled, but view - not, so image will be outside of view borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just force your `ImageView` not to scale the resource when its loading it into the view. Use the following code for setting the `ImageView`'s resource:

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), resId, options);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**And remember to recycle the bitmap when your `ImageView` is no longer being used**

Comment: thank you for you reply. but whatever. when i scale up my view - image bitmap inside - will be scaled related to view size ((((

Comment: Well yea it will since you've  got your scale type set to fitxy. You didn't write anything in your question that would suggest its undesired behaviour